What is the impact of taking a job in a less prestigious field?
I am working for aerospace place right now but it's inconsistent work, I got offered a position in a less prestigious area(agriculture) with somewhat similar work but in a different domain/application.
What are the consequences in taking such a position if I want to revisit a more prestigious industry in the future?

Why do you think aerospace is less prestigious than agriculture? If the work is largely similar, why would it make a difference what the industry is?

Aerospace is definitely considered more prestigious

@FourierFlux - if I may, how old are you approximately?

It completely depends on the type of work you're doing. You'll need to give us more information about that. If I go purely by your user name, then signal's processing is valuable in any industry, and it really doesn't matter which industry you work in as long as the work you do relates to your core speciality.

If you are trying to be someone who only works in prestigious fields then the impact will be you will be working as what you perceive to be a less prestigious field. A bit of advice, if you find yourself in this situation don't tell the other people there what you think of them and the company.

Outside of a academia, people care a lot more about what you achieved than what/who you did it fir, though IT Manager for Los Alamos Labs is more pressure than IT Manager for Joe's Department Store even if the tasks were similar. (On the other hand, CTO of Joe's might rank above IT Director of Los Alamos depending on exactly what you did in each role.)

When working in industry (as opposed to my impression of academia) you are extremely unlikely to be judged when applying for future jobs by the "prestige" of the specific industry you work in. Indeed, I have never heard of it happening, and would not consider any industry I have worked in to be more prestigious than any other.
For example, I currently work for a company in the hospitality industry. My previous employer was in the finance industry, and I work with colleagues whos previous employers include the aerospace industry, the agriculture industry, and the gaming industry. None of those industries affect our current positions, and they were not considered during the hiring process.
Instead, future employers will consider the specific positions you held with past employers, and the responsibilities you carried out when you held those positions.
If you have worked for an especially prestigious company then that may make a difference, but I would still expect the specific position and experience gained in that company to be more important than anything.

There's a few industries that could be considered poisonous, but unless you've left a trail of burning crypto startups in your wake it probably won't matter too much.
